# Why this code isn't compile with VS2010 and gcc 4.8.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc

Simple, please,look this code:

```
namespace B
{

    struct A{ int i; } ;

    A getA(int i);
}

//        ____ if I'll delete '::' then program successfull compiled.
//       /
::B::A  ::B::getA(int i){ ::B::A a = {i}; return a;}

#include <cstdio>
int main()
{

  ::B::A a = ::B::getA(2);

  printf("%d\n", a.i);

}
```

Error list  VS2010:

```
1>main.cpp(94): error C3083: 'B': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
1>main.cpp(94): error C2039: 'getA' : is not a member of 'B::A'
1>main.cpp(88) : see declaration of 'B::A'
1>error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>main.cpp(94): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'B::A' to 'int'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>main.cpp(94): error C2617: 'getA' : inconsistent return statement
1>main.cpp(94) : see declaration of 'getA'
```

Gcc.4.8.1 error list ( [from ideone.com](http://ideone.com/TG4Hzr)):

```
   prog.cpp:10:1: error: ‘B’ in ‘struct B::A’ does not name a type
 ::B::A  ::B::getA(int i){ ::B::A a = {i}; return a;}
 ^
```

**Q: It's a bug or I'm not understand something ?**

Comment: as far as I know "::" without any qualifier before means "find it in the global namespace". So it's quite misleading for the compiler that might think it's a class. Not sure why though

Comment: @DavidKernin: Because the whitespace before it has no significance, so it attaches to the preceding `A`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I completely overlooked that.  Good eye!

Comment: I didn't know it, I really need to remember that next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, whitespace between tokens has no significance except where it's needed to separate tokens. So this:

```
::B::A  ::B::getA(...)
```

is equivalent to

```
::B::A::B::getA(...)
```

To indicate that they are two separate qualified names, use parentheses around the function name:

```
::B::A (::B::getA)(...)
```

or, as you say, remove the top-level qualifier (although that might lead to confusion if you have other things called `B` in scope).

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of the compiler seeing different code than you think it sees.  Those are incredibly hard to debug because the error messages seem to be irrelevant and almost random.

The problem is that the compiler ignores the whitespace between `::B::A` and `::B::getA`, so it believes you're talking about the function `::B::A::B::getA()`.  It doesn't matter that you can't be defining that function (there is no return type in the compiler's view of things), or calling that function (based on the function body that appears later).  The compiler doesn't have enough knowledge to work out the ambiguity.  Instead, it realizes that it never saw a declaration for the type `::B::A::B`, and gives you an error message.